# How to use R markdown to convert block of un-commented text to text that is rendered/displayed as commented text

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I am using `knitr`, and have text blocks that I would like to render in R markdown as if they were commented output. How can I get `knitr` to add left-justified comment symbols to my text?

I.e., I have lots of text like that below, which I have copy-pasted from the R command console of R studio, in my `.Rmd` file:

```
Fixed effects:
                          Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)                723.793     27.472  26.346
GroupCond.Treatmenthomo      6.145      4.792   1.282
GroupCond.Treatmenthetero   20.739      4.796   4.324
```

And I would like knitr to render it like this, in the style of a commented code block:

```
##  Fixed effects:
##                            Estimate Std. Error t value
##  (Intercept)                723.793     27.472  26.346
##  GroupCond.Treatmenthomo      6.145      4.792   1.282
##  GroupCond.Treatmenthetero   20.739      4.796   4.324
```

Is there a way to do this?

What I am really trying to do here is show the steps in a modeling process without actually burdening my `.Rmd` file with command execution steps that would require loading data into the `.Rmd` environment and time consuming model fitting.  And, in showing the steps, I want to make a clear distinction between modeling commands and model output.

Comment: If you are using RStudio try highlighting the text in question and `Ctrl+Shift+C`

Comment: Thanks. I see that option under the "Code" menu item, but this does not do anything in my `.Rmd` document, although it works to add a single comment marker (`#`) to lines in a `.R` file.

Comment: Is the text within a code block?

Comment: When I `Ctrl+Shift+C` within a code block, it does add the `#` symbol to the left of the text, but then the `#` symbol does not print when the text is rendered, and the text is not rendered with fixed width font.

Comment: I wonder why this post has been down-voted.  It seems to me this is a legitimate question of some general applicabilty.  One often comes across this kind of formatting, and it would be good to make the method for it public.

Comment: You have to fill in your question more. You should have code blocks with your header since it affects the solution. That is the part with '''r,.....

Comment: Your question is unclear. This text looks like the result of some `summary(...)`, but your question reads like it is your own input. The solution depends on this. For the output of a code chunk, it involves the `opts_chunk` `comment` (see http://yihui.name/knitr/options/)

Comment: Copying and pasting results from the console to and RMD file is quite orthogonal to the idea of reproducible research. What do you [really](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) want to do?

Comment: Thanks.  I have added description of my overall objective to the end of the question.

Answer (score 0):

try escaping your markdown text.. Remember to end each line with two spaces to force a line break

```
\##  Fixed effects:  
\##                            Estimate Std. Error t value  
\##  (Intercept)                723.793     27.472  26.346  
\##  GroupCond.Treatmenthomo      6.145      4.792   1.282  
\##  GroupCond.Treatmenthetero   20.739      4.796   4.324
```

Answer (score 0):

Summing up, the question is about not actually computing results, but having output (code and results) that *looks like* the results were computed in the document.

Assume we have the following code that generates a `data.frame`:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, char = LETTERS[1:10])
```

Assume we don't want to confuse the reader with the "confusing code" that generates `dat`. But we want to show that there is a command `summary(dat)` and we want to include its output. The output is supposed to look like we actually executed the command.

I propose three different solutions. I leave it to the reader to execture the snippets in order to see the output.

## Execute everything, hide what's confusing

Simple version:

````
```{r, echo = FALSE}
dat <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, char = LETTERS[1:10])
```

```{r}
summary(dat)
```
````

Advanced version (identical output!):

````
```{r, echo = 2}
dat <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, char = LETTERS[1:10])
summary(dat)
```
````

Explanation: See documentation for [`echo`](http://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

- **Pro:** Reproducible.
- **Con:** Execution time if loading/generating the data is computationally intensive (as suggested in the question). Note that knitr's [cache](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/) may be a way out in case of repeated execution.

## Load the data

In a normal R session, generate/compute the objects that are to be printed and use `save` to save them to a file. In the document, `load` that file (either in a separate chunk or using the `echo` trick from above).

````
```{r, echo = 2}
load("dat.RData")
summary(dat)
```
````

- **Pro:** Generation of `dat` doesn't matter for the document.
- **Con:** File needs to be created in advance; harms reproducibility.

## Pretend execution

The question suggested to show text that was copied from the console as if it was output.

````
```{r, eval = FALSE}
summary(dat)
```

```{r, echo = FALSE}
cat("       ID             char  
 Min.   : 1.00   A      :1  
 1st Qu.: 3.25   B      :1  
 Median : 5.50   C      :1  
 Mean   : 5.50   D      :1  
 3rd Qu.: 7.75   E      :1  
 Max.   :10.00   F      :1  
                 (Other):4  ")
```
````

- **Pro:** Nothing (except `cat`) needs to be exectured in the document (if you want to call this an advantage).
- **Con:** Not reproducible. Easy to forget updating to output when code changes.